# Placing an x axis on top of a bar plot with negative y values

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, axis, axis-labels

I have some data for various experimental treatments which are negative values. I'd like to plot the x-axis on top of the bar-plot and have the labels located the same as if it were a traditional bar-plot at the centre of the bars.

I've checked all over and can't find anything that lets me name the axis labels with words, only setting tick marks and numbers.

Here's the data: - "wp_means"

```
>         12         15          3          6          9    Control 
-0.3000000 -0.2416667 -0.3416667 -0.3916667 -0.2750000 -0.2750000 
        DL 
-0.2833333
```

Here's my code to plot the bar-plot. I can omit the x-axis from it's usual position, but I can't seem to get it on top with its labels etc. where I want it to be.

```
cols<-c("blue1", "cyan","chartreuse","mediumspringgreen","maroon1","orange","red")
    wp<-data.frame(a=c(wp_means),b=c(12,15,3,6,9,"Control","DL"))
    wp$c=factor(wp$b, levels = c("Control",15,"DL",12,9,6,3))
    wp <- wp[order(wp$c), ]
    barplot(height=wp$a,names.arg=wp$c,col=cols,main="Water Potential",las=1,xaxt="n",
    ylab = "Water potential 
    (MPA)",pch=21,bg="black",cex=0.7,cex.lab=0.8,font.lab=2,
    cex.axis=0.7,font.axis=2,cex.main=1,ylim=c(-0.5,0),xaxt="n")
```

And here's the plot: I'd like to have the labels on the upper x axis in the order they appear in `"levels = c("Control"....)"` per above. I'd also like to set a label title the same way one would usually do with `xlab="some name"` without it interfering with my chart title.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you break that down for me a little more please? Using the data I have, where do I set the bar-plot positions for     bp<-barplot(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate method I believe is to use the `pos=` argument when adding an `?axis` to your existing `barplot`. You will need to save the positions of the bar centres first however. Like `bp <- barplot(...)`, so:

```
wp_means <- c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.34, -0.39, -0.275, -0.275, -0.283)

cols<-c("blue1", "cyan","chartreuse","mediumspringgreen","maroon1","orange","red")

wp <-data.frame(a=c(wp_means),b=c(12,15,3,6,9,"Control","DL"))

wp$c=factor(wp$b, levels = c("Control",15,"DL",12,9,6,3))
wp <- wp[order(wp$c), ]
bp <- barplot(height=wp$a, names.arg=wp$c, col=cols, las=1, xaxt="n",
         ylab = "Water potential (MPA)",
         pch=21, bg="black", cex=0.7, cex.lab=0.8, font.lab=2,
         cex.axis=0.7, font.axis=2, cex.main=1, ylim=c(-0.5,0), xaxt="n")

axis(side=3, pos=0, at=bp, labels=levels(wp$c))
title(main="Water Potential", line=3)
```

Note the use of `line=3` when adding a `title()` which pushes your chart title away from the group labels.

[image]

Comment: Great!!! Last question. How do I get the font and size of the new x labels to match the font of the y labels?     font=2, cex.axis=0.8. And the size of the title font as cex=1

Comment: Don't worry. I got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: The same way you set it previously `axis(side=3, pos=0, at=bp, labels=levels(wp$c), cex.axis=0.8, font=2)`  and `title(main="Water Potential", line=3, cex.main=1)`